# Does this integral inequality hold?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, schwartz-space

Take the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ with family of norms:
$$\|f\|_{\alpha,\beta} = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}}|(\partial^{\alpha}f)(x)x^{\beta}|.$$
Now consider the following mapping:
$$\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \ni f \mapsto g(x) =\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\varphi(y)f(x+y)dy$$
Does the following inequality:
$$\|g\|_{\alpha,\beta} \le \|f\|_{\alpha,\beta}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|\varphi(y)|dy$$
hold?

I sketched some calculations:
$$\bigg{|}\bigg{(}\partial^{\alpha}\int \varphi(y)f(x+y)dy\bigg{)}x^{\beta}\bigg{|} = \bigg{|}\bigg{(}\int \varphi(y)(\partial^{\alpha}f)(x+y)dy\bigg{)}x^{\beta}\bigg{|} \le \int |\varphi(y)||x^{\beta}(\partial^{\alpha}f)(x+y)|dy \le \int |\varphi(y)|\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}}|x^{\beta}(\partial^{\alpha}f)(x)|dy = \|f\|_{\alpha,\beta}\int|\varphi(y)|dy$$
but I am not sure if the steps are right.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks right, assuming $\phi \in L^1$ so that the differentiation under the integral makes sense.